# Python OpenWRT crontab

Tags: python, cron, snmp, openwrt

Im trying to run python script on OpenWrt box:

```
#!/root/system/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen([r"snmpget","-v","1","-c","public","-Oqv","-Ln", "192.168.1.1","1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.7"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
data = [r"curl","-d","iface_id=1&content="+ str(p).rstrip() ,"http://192.168.1.5:8080/stat/add_istat/"]
a = subprocess.Popen(data, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

It's geting data over snmp, then post data by curl to local server. 
Its working ok from shell:

```
root@OpenWrt:~/python# ./w.py 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0    34    0     6    0    28     31    146 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

I can see data in DB.
but from cron:

```
0-55/5 * * * * /root/python/w.py
```

I see in logread:

```
Dec 20 23:30:01 OpenWrt cron.err crond[1039]: USER root pid 16141 cmd /root/python/w.py
```

But no data in DB :( and nothing in httpd access.log :( why?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that snmpget or curl are not in the path of cron?

Comment: With full path to snmpget and curl not working too :(
With .sh script:
root@OpenWrt:~# cat add.sh 
/root/system/usr/bin/python /root/python/w.py
also not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I replace curl with python urllib request and now its working! :)

```
url = 'http://192.168.1.5:8080/stat/add_istat/"' # write ur URL here

values = {'iface_id' : '1', #write ur specific key/value pair
          'content' : str(p).rstrip(),
         }
try:
   data = urllib.urlencode(values)
   req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
   response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
   the_page = response.read()
   print the_page
except Exception, detail:
   print "Err ", detail
```